# How could I validate the date range in C# using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

my fromdatepicker1 and todatepicker2. I want to validate the date range of the two. and it will always be fromdate is < todate. and my date format is dd/mm/yy, how should I write it in Jquery?

here is my from date textbox

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtFromDateBank" 
                        ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="asdf" SetFocusOnError="true" InitialValue="" 
                        EnableClientScript="true" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller" 
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="AddBankDetails">Please specify date</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
```

heres my todate textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtToDateBank" runat="server"  class="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840953/net-date-validation-with-jquery

Comment: yeah, but I cant understand the concept of the datepickers because my format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: can you help me dude, I dont have idea what to do :(

Comment: @Therence, use this link for help http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validating-date-range-in-any-format-with-jquery-ui-datepickers

Answer (score 0):

Try these tools

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

use the CustomeValidator control and set the ClientValidationFunction property to a javascript/jquery function. the js function might look like this -

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function CheckDate(sender, args)
{
    var strDate = $(fromdatetextbox).val();
    var dateParts = strDate.split("/"); 
    var fromdate = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

    strDate = $(todatetextbox).val();
    dateParts = strDate.split("/"); 
    todate = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

    if(fromdate > todate)
        args.IsValid = false;
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}
// -->
</script>
```

you can learn more about customvalidator in this link
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx

## Update

here is what the full code should look like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs"   Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function CheckDate(sender, args) {
        var strDate = $('#<%= textBoxFromDate.ClientID %>').val();
        var dateParts = strDate.split("/");
        var fromdate = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

        strDate = $('#<%= textBoxToDate.ClientID %>').val();
        dateParts = strDate.split("/");
        todate = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

        if (fromdate > todate)
            args.IsValid = false;
        else
            args.IsValid = true;
    }
    // -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxFromDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
            ControlToValidate="textBoxFromDate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
            ControlToValidate="textBoxFromDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


            <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxToDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
            ControlToValidate="textBoxToDate" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
            ControlToValidate="textBoxToDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how should i write in in my asp textbox?

Comment: @Therence 
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
                ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate" ControlToValidate="txtToDateBank"></asp:CustomValidator>
this will validate the textbox, but to pick date you can use **JqueryUI Datpicker** or **Ajax Control Toolkit Datepicker**; both of them will work with this validator.

Comment: can you post the whole answers? plss